# Can we talk about exponential translations? And also plane vectors as variables etc..

Tags: vectors, linear-transformations, transformation, plane-geometry

I have a pretty interesting theory,  but i lack A LOT in math knowledge. 
Also this might be a little longer than usual questions and full of broken english so i apologize :

I'm trying to find out if we can imagine a plane (which will be prolonged to a space if what I'm saying is logical) that itself is a function of time. 
Like we can apply translations and rotations on a plane so i thought maybe the vectors (i and j)  could also vary in an exponential way (what the title says) Now what got me into thinking of this is seeing my friend moving at a linearly increasing speed while mine  was exponential (as the acceleration was decreasing over time) 
And i thought of myself as an axis vector. 
My question is
If we know at which speed he moves and at which speed i am accelerating, can we determine his position at any date? (Of course in comparison to my original position at t=0).
Ask if something is unclear I'll try to clarify is as much as possible. thank you

Comment: Probably. You will need to provide more information about how you and your friend are moving as a function of time.

Comment: If you have a function for your own absolute position like $f(t) = (e^t,e^t)$ and another for your friend's absolute position like $g(t) = (t^2,0)$ I think you can just take the difference $g(t) - f(t)$ to put it in your own frame of reference.